# Debug on HTC Wildfire S - Error with Adb

Tags: android, adb

I'm using an htc wildfire S with Android 2.3.3 to debug my app. But every time I deploy it, I get message:

```
[2011-08-01 16:10:48 - motodev_pckafv] Failed to install motodev_pckafv.apk on device 'HT15ATT00191': Connection refused: connect
[2011-08-01 16:10:48 - motodev_pckafv] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Connection refused: connect
[2011-08-01 16:10:48 - motodev_pckafv] Launch canceled!
```

So, i run command "adb devices" on prompt and get message:

```
* daemon not running. Starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Then, run app again in eclipse and now works. I need to do this every time.

Anyone know the solution?

Ty

**edit:**

When I use HTC magic 2.1, works normally. The error only happens with the HTC wildfire 2.3.3.

Comment: Did you restart, eclipse, the phone, the computer (in that order)? I usually have problems with Eclipse going crazy and all it takes is a close/reopen of Eclipse and/or worst case scenario I logoff or restart the whole computer.

Comment: I did this, but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

you have to set from phone -> sync and yu have to download htc sync driver. (whnen install disable antivirus) After you can install it from eclipse and from htc sync , you add the file apk from  your application bin directory

Comment: but i dont want do copy .apk every time i change app.

Comment: You can see the device from eclupse. But take care sometimes , even if you run again the changes won t be visible , I had to uninstall application from phone sometimes.

Comment: Ok. I had never needded to reinstall, only rebuild and deploy app from eclipse works, but this isnt my problem.

Comment: in eclipse when you go on project and look at properties android it is set to be google api , 2.3.3? eclipse won t recognize phone if the project has other version that phone.

Comment: My problem isnt eclipse, it is working fine. My problem is that the phone refuses to connect to the adb at deploy time.